# How can i get loop and filter at once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

```js
    const count = [
        {number: 1},
        {number: 2},
        {number: 3},
        {number: 4},
        {number: 5},
        {number: 6},
        {number: 7},
        {number: 8},
        {number: 9},
        {number: 10},
        {number: 11},
        {number: 12},
        {number: 13},
        {number: 14},
        {number: 15}
        ];
 
 
    for(let i = 0;i < count.length; i++) {

    document.write(count[i].number);
    }
```

If the main number what i want to get out the loop is 5. But i want to write out one above 5 and one under 5. So  456. How can i achieve that?

Comment: `document.write(count[i - 1] + count[i] + count[i + 1]);`

Comment: @JacobSchneider but watch out for an out of bounds exception!

Comment: `count[i - 1] || ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to filter out the number which you want you can use an `if` statement to check if the current object's number `count[i].number` is the value you want, and then if it is, print out its associated values.

You can access the object before and after by changing your value of `i`. Using `i-1` you will get the element before your current value. Similarly, using `i+1` you will go to the object after your current value.

Lastly, you should check the value of `i` to make sure that it falls within the array. For instance, if you chose to find the number `1` it has no before object, and so you need to check for this case!

See working example below:

```js
const count = [
        {number: 1},
        {number: 2},
        {number: 3},
        {number: 4},
        {number: 5},
        {number: 6},
        {number: 7},
        {number: 8},
        {number: 9},
        {number: 10},
        {number: 11},
        {number: 12},
        {number: 13},
        {number: 14},
        {number: 15}
        ];
 
const toFind = 5;
for(let i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  if(count[i].number == toFind) {
    if(i-1 >= 0) console.log(count[i-1].number);
    console.log(count[i].number);
    if(i+1 < count.length) console.log(count[i+1].number);
    break; // complete loop cycle
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most algorithmically efficient solution. One small optimization to make is to `break;` at the end of the `if()` statement, as you have already found your number and iterating the rest of the array is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `needle` is unique, you can [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the numbers you want, then [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to print them.

```js
const needle = 5
const haystack = [
  {number: 1},
  {number: 2},
  {number: 3},
  {number: 4},
  {number: 5},
  {number: 6},
  {number: 7},
  {number: 8},
  {number: 9},
  {number: 10},
  {number: 11},
  {number: 12},
  {number: 13},
  {number: 14},
  {number: 15}
]

haystack
  .sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number) // skip this if haystack is already sorted.
  .filter(el => [needle - 1, needle, needle + 1].includes(el.number))
  .forEach(el => {
    document.write(el.number)
  })
```

Note that you have to guard against `needle = 0` which has no `-1` and `needle = 15` which has no `+1`.

Comment: More generally I believe their query is "I need to get X number, and show the values at x-1 and x+1"

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Ah, true. Edited.

Comment: No need of filter here. why not do it simply with one forEach ?

Comment: @CodeManiac You mean using an `if` within `forEach`?

Comment: @NikKyriakides yes. there's no need of one extra loop

Comment: @CodeManiac Because I find using `filter` more idiomatic. Plus I'm not looping over `haystack` twice. The `forEach` loops only over the 3 filtered elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
        const count = [
      { number: 1 },
      { number: 2 },
      { number: 3 },
      { number: 4 },
      { number: 5 },
      { number: 6 },
      { number: 7 },
      { number: 8 },
      { number: 9 },
      { number: 10 },
      { number: 11 },
      { number: 12 },
      { number: 13 },
      { number: 14 },
      { number: 15 }
    ];
    var index = count.findIndex(item => item.number === 5);
    document.write(count[index - 1].number);
    document.write(count[index].number);
    document.write(count[index + 1].number);
```

Comment: Make sure to bounds check your `index-1` and `index+1` or you'll get an exception for `undefined.number`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and based on range you can write to document.

```js
const count = [{number: 1},{number: 2},{number: 3},{number: 4},{number: 5},{number: 6},{number: 7},{number: 8},{number: 9},{number: 10},{number: 11},{number: 12},{number: 13},{number: 14},{number: 15}];
        
count.forEach(({number})=> {
  if(number>3 && number<7){
    document.write(number)
  }
})
```